# Navigation Controller with Flip animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, navigationcontroller

I've just started to learn to code in Swift and in the process of building a restaurant iOS app.

I basically have a table view of restaurants with a Map button on the top right, embedded in the nav. When you click on it, I like the view to flip to reveal a map.

How do I go about doing this?

The push segue seems to fixate on a default animation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `UIView.transitionFromView` method. First you will have to build your map view in code. Assuming you have that already you do following thing:

```
    UIView.transitionFromView(self.view,
      toView: yourMapView,
      duration: someDuration,
      options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft,
      completion: nil)
```

in your UITabBarItem action.

Answer (score 0):

You can present the new view controller modally and set its modalTransitionStyle to . FlipHorizontal. For example:

```
let mapViewController = MapViewController()
mapViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .FlipHorizontal
self.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```